# How can I make each module instance read from a unique file?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, iverilog

In top.v, I generate X_MAX*Y_MAX instances of a `pe` module.  In pe.v, I want to initialize a memory generated specifically for that instance.  For example, at x=0,y=1: "pe_memory_x0_y0.dat".  This is what my top-level module looks like:

```
genvar x, y;
    generate for (y = 0; y < Y_MAX; y = y + 1) begin : ys
        for (x = 0; x < X_MAX; x = x + 1) begin : xs
         pe #(
            .X_MAX(X_MAX),
            .Y_MAX(Y_MAX),
            .X(x),
            .Y(y)
            )
            pe_inst(
                .clk(clk),
                ...
            );
```

Inside pe.v, things like

```
$display("Loading pe memory at (%0d,%0d)", X, Y);
```

work in an `initial` block!  But when I need to `$readmem$`,

```
$readmemb({"pe_memory_", X, "_y", Y, ".dat"}, n_bound_sel_memory);
```

does not work:

> X has indefinite width

Specifying a width for X, a `parameter` whose values comes from a `genvar`, just throws more errors.

I'm targeting Xilinx FPGAs, and I'm trying to simulate my design with `iverilog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$sformatf` to  construct a file name:

```
$readmemb($sformatf("pe_memory_%0d_y%0d.dat", X, Y), n_bound_sel_memory);
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.3.3 *Formatting data to a string*

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't able to simulate this in iverilog (I think that's because IEEE Std 1800-2017 isn't yet supported in iverilog?), but this works perfectly within Vivado simulator.